# Consul-Template returns empty map?

Tags: go-templates, hashicorp-vault, consul-template

**Hi everyone,**

I am trying to fetch a client token from approle auth method in vault. I have configured consul-template that it gets the role-id and the secret-id then, uses them to get the client_token at auth/approle/login end point. What is really weird is that first two steps are successfully executed and returned the data, however, getting the client_token is the struggle here. I analyzed the requests using wireshark and checked the response for the request that asks for the client_token, and it shows clearly the json result with the client_token included. But consul template does recognize the return and gives me this result:

`{322a47b9-bf23-193d-8117-228637253fde  0 false map[] [] 0xc42001cf50 <nil>}`.

The same way is used to request the secret-id but consul-template has successfully returned it and has recognized the json object. Isn't that weird?!

You can find the consul template below:

```
{{define "token" }}
{{ with secret "auth/approle/role/python-role/role-id" }}{{ $role:= (print "role_id= " .Data.role_id) }}
{{ with secret "auth/approle/role/python-role/secret-id" "role_name= python-role" }}{{ $secret:= (print "secret_id= " .Data.secret_id) }}
{{- with secret "auth/approle/login/" $role $secret -}}{{ . }}{{ end }}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}

{{template "token"}}
```

Also, below is the wireshark trace that I used to check that the request went right:
[image]
**Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks in advance.**